# How to disable validation when TextBox property IsEnabled is false?

Tags: c#, xaml

I found various answers on StackOverflow, and none of them helped me.
I want turn off validation on TextBox when `IsEnabled="false"`
What am I missing here?

```
  <TextBox x:Name="idTxtBox">

        <!--This is where I tried to disable validation-->
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>

        <!--I want to disable these validation rules-->
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="ID" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <val:RequiredFieldValidation ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                    <val:IsNumberValidation Min="1" Max="250" ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue"/>
                    <val:UniqueIDTag ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>



        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <!--........-->
      </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly how your code works, and a more specific explanation of what you want the code to do and why your current approach doesn't accomplish that, it's hard to know for sure what answer would serve you best. However, it seems to me that you're on the right track, you're just changing the wrong property.

I would not expect removing the `ErrorTemplate` value to affect *whether* validation occurs, just what the user sees. If you want to remove the validation, you should do just that: remove the validation. For example:

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <p:Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <p:Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ID}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </p:Style.Triggers>
    </p:Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

(Ignore the `p:` namespace…I just put that in there so that the code formatter Stack Overflow is using won't get side-tracked by the `Style` element name.)

In other words, the validation is included in the binding. So, when you don't want the validation to occur, change the binding to one without validation (and since the control is disabled, you can omit the `UpdateSourceTrigger` value as well).